# jQuery: div doesn't appear until second click? I want it on the first. =\

Tags: jquery

First click: empty floatymessage div. second click and after: works.

jQuery:

```
function floatymessage(message){
    var box = $j(".floatymessage")
    if (box.length == 0) {
        $j('body').append("<div class='floatymessage'></div>");
    }
    box.html(message);
    // center it
    box.css("left", ( $j(window).width() - box.width() ) / 2+$j(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    box.fadeIn('slow');

    setTimeout(function(){$j('.floatymessage').fadeOut('slow');},3500);
}
```

link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="floatymessage('Asking questions is not allowed.');"></a>
```

css for floatymessoge:

```
div.floatymessage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity:0.75;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: what is this 'j' doing between your '$' and '('? Also, what does the CSS look like for `floatymessage`?

Comment: @Hristo - DerNalia is running in `.noConflict()` mode. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @patrick dw, yep. 
@hristo: posted my css

Comment: Your code works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/YH99G/ Are you sure jQuery is fully loaded *before* you click?

Comment: I am not sure. Don't know how to ensure that.

Comment: @patrick... hmmm... I haven't heard of `noConflict()` mode. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: @Hristo - It is handy when you need to use more than one javascript library that tries to use the same global variable `$` as a reference. In an earlier question, the OP noted that prototypejs was also being used. jQuery has an article on using different libraries together. http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: @patrick... thank you for the explanation. that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic with box was missing a step, if it is not already in the dom you need to set your variable 'box' to the new div:

```
if (box.length == 0) {
  box = $j("<div class='floatymessage'></div>");
  $j('body').append(box);
}
```

further,

You can use the method you have setup but when using an anchor tag to fire a javascript event you need to add a return false to stop it from processing it like a normal link.

```
<a id="mine" href="#" onclick="floatymessage('msg');return false;">run</a>
```

It is a better practice to bind events in this case:

```
$j("#mine").click(function() { floatymessage('msg'); });
```

You could achieve the same effect using a span tag instead of an anchor tag that wants to navigate to a url.

```
<span id="mine" onclick="floatymessage('msg');">run</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the click event with jQuery

```
$(function() { // after the document is loaded
    $j("a#someId").click(function(e){ // when the anchor is clicked (give it an ID)
        e.preventDefault();
        floatymessage("Asking questions is not allowed."); 
    });
});
```

Comment: after the first click of any button, they all work. (i have three buttons with different messages)

Comment: my guess is your document isn't finished loading