# Jquery Modal popup opens on second click not on first

Tags: asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-postback

i got stuck with jquery modal dialog. my modal shows by clicking twice on the button and spoils the markup also on the page
i read no of posts including stack overflow 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050329/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-first-click-but-does-on-second-click-why)

AND [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355739/jquery-div-doesnt-appear-until-second-click-i-want-it-on-the-first)

but my issue doesn't match both.So i request you to please not vote down the question.

i am using the following code to show modal

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function overlayclickclose() {
            if (closedialog) {
                jQuery('#mydialog').dialog('close');
                             }
            closedialog = 1;
                                    }

            jQuery('#mydialog').dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            height: 400,
            resizable: false,
            open: function() { closedialog = 1; jQuery(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose); },
            focus: function() { closedialog = 1; },
            close: function() { jQuery(document).unbind('click'); }
            });
            </script>
```

now here is my div to be shown as popup

```
<div id="mydialog"><NL:TemplatePicker ID="TemplatePicker1" Runat="server"></NL:TemplatePicker></div>
```

And i am calling the modal on Click of a button by calling it in asp.net code behind like this

```
protected void btnChooseTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "change", "jQuery('#mydialog').dialog('open');closedialog = 1;jQuery('#mydialog').parent().appendTo(jQuery('form:aspnetForm'));", true);
    }
```

my page uses ajax updatepanel.

any help would be regarded. if you need anything more to knowthe problem better let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Devjosh: It looks like you are registering the open dialog in the btnChooseTemplate click. This means the open script will not be registered until after the first click. Try moving the client script block registration into the page load function so that it's registered each time your page loads, ready for the first click each time.

Comment: i moved the registered client script method to page_load event but still it does the same